# how to move rows up down in database with php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

```
/// SQL Query

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `move_row` 
USE `move_row`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_cate` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `tbl_cate` (`id`, `name`, `ordering`) VALUES
    (1, 'a', 1),
    (2, 'b', 2),
    (3, 'c', 3),
    (4, 'd', 4),
    (5, 'e', 5),
    (6, 'f', 6);


/// My code    

<?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("move_row");
?>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>N</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Ordering</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_cate ORDER BY ordering ASC");
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $rows['id'] ;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rows['name'] ;?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="index.php?action=move_up&move_up_id<?php echo $rows['id'];?>">Up</a>
            <a href="index.php?action=move_down&move_down_id<?php echo $rows['id'];?>">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>

<?php
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] =="move_up")){

            //// please help

    }else if(isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] =="move_down")){

            //// please help
    }
?>
```

Comment: What does it mean to move rows up and down in a database?

Comment: rows don't like elevator rides

Comment: @Drew I hear they prefer the escalator

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: You mean sort order the table rows? You don't need to do on database, you can manage by changing sorting with jQuery or Javascript, example: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html

Comment: How did JS enter into this. Ok, let's talk about Go Programming too :p

Comment: Table rows are not stored in an order that you can effect. The only thing you can do is create another column lets call it `rank` into which you put a number. You can then sort on that number, and change those numbers to effect the order that you see the rows when you sort on that column

Comment: Ok, thanks for comment. But I still understand, could you show me, how to move rows when click to up and click to down table rows  with php mysql? If possible do have example for me to do like this.